# Como saber quais variáveis estão definidas?

Tags: python, variáveis

Existe alguma função que retorne o nome das variáveis definidas em uma instância do Python? Alguma coisa similar ao comando `who` no MatLab que retorna os nomes das variáveis definidas pelo usuário.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com o [Stack em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633127/viewing-all-defined-variables) seria da seguinte forma:

- `dir()` retorna uma lista de variáveis no escopo
- `globals()` retorna um dicionário de variáveis globais
- `locals()` retorna um dicionário de variáveis locais

Comment: Essas funções servem, mas não é do jeito que eu gostaria porque retornam também tudo o que é definido automaticamente e também pelas importações dos módulos. Fiz um script para filtrar pelo tipo de variável.

Comment: No link em ingles tem varios exemplos diferentes que talvez ajudem.

Answer (score 3):

Tem, não sei se do jeito que gostaria:

- [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) lista as variáveis do escopo específico
- [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) retorna as variáveis globais (que deveria ser evitadas)
- [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) retorna as variáveis da função